# How to deactivate Firebug for a website / url?

Tags: firebug

I would like Firebug not to load for particular sites. I see that it is enabled on some sites and on the others it is not.
Is this possible to manage the list of websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Firefox? Then you can easily enable and disable with the button on thenavigation bar. else there is no way to manage the list of Websites where it should turn off or on.

Comment: I should have known that the answer would be somthing obvious. Thanks.